# PHP Echo If URL ends with text

Tags: php

If there anyway to show an echo in php if the url ends with some specified text?

For example ...

If the url ends with ?login=failed

is it posible for php to echo...

Echo 'Login Failed, please try again'; ... for example?

Comment: The text you're talking about is called the query string, and can be accessed via the superglobal variable `$_GET`. Try loading a URL with some stuff in the query string, and then `print_r($_GET)` to see what's there and how you could access it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if `$_GET['login']` is set, and if it is, check if it equals `'failed'`:

```
if( isset( $_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == 'failed') {
    echo 'Login Failed, please try again';
}
```